# Right-censored predictor where censorship means "never"

Tags: missing-data, predictor, censoring

My major predictor is "time to consultation" (of the specialist), which ranges from 0 to roughly 72 hours. There are also patients in this group whose value is "never". That is the procedure in question was performed without ever bothering to consult the specialist. I have a right-censored predictor, where the censorship means "never". I have the task of modeling both whether or not consultation has an effect and how much an effect time to consultation has. I could treat the time values of all the non-consults as "missing" and have a second variable indicating whether or not a consult was done. Is that optimal?